# How to include value within he file= string of a write.xlsx command

Tags: r

I'm struggling with finding out how to get a vlaue to resolve within speech marks. In the blow example, the is a load of other code logic between the setting of outputfolder and the write.xlsx line. Any suggestions?

```
client_name  <-"client a"
project_name <-"project x"
outputfolder <-"D:/client_abc_folder"

write.xlsx(df, file="outputfolder/client_name_project_name.xlsx", sheetName="my analysis", row.names = FALSE, append=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `paste0(outputfolder, "/", client_name, "_", project_name, ".xlsx")`